# coffeescript for in bug?

Tags: coffeescript

On coffeescript loop 'for'

eg.
if 1 < x, code like below:

```
console.debug i for i in [1..0]
```

Generated code is:

```
var i;
for (i = 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  console.debug(i);
}
```

if 1 > x,code like below:

```
console.debug i for i in [1..2]
```

Generated code is:

```
var i;
for (i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
  console.debug(i);
}
```

If i want write that javascript.How to ?

```
for(var i=1;i<=0;i++){
  console.debug(i);
}
```

Because i don't know the condition is greater than left side or less than left side.
But i just want it i++

What's wrong with me?
EDIT BELOW:
For coffeescript's feature,I add condition before the loop or add condition on for loop.
eg:

```
if x - y >=1
  console.debug i for i in [1..x-y]
```

or

```
console.debug i for i in [1..x-y] and x-y >=1
```

That's my way.Some one have good advice?

Comment: What do you want to do with that loop? CoffeeScript doesn't generate that code because it would be an infinite loop unless you're doing something with i inside the loop.

Comment: You see the condition,i is 1,1<=0 is false,so it would ignore the loop.

Comment: Oops, sorry. But CoffeeScript does a forward/backward loop depending on whether start is less than or greater than end. You cannot generate this code directly AFAIK.

Comment: Please click the unresearch button for me.It' too strict for me.Thanks.

Comment: @sjbwylbs Unresearch? Do you mean close/delete? If you want your question to be deleted, just flag it with a custom message, and explain that you're the OP and want the question to be deleted.

Comment: @Dogbert,I means that.If you down vote this question.Please cancel it.

Comment: @sjbwylbs, sorry, but I didn't downvote it. Someone else must have done it.

Comment: just use `while` loop for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to do this:

```
console.debug i for i in [1..x-y] by 1
```

Which gets compiled to:

```
var i, _i, _ref;

for (i = _i = 1, _ref = x - y; _i <= _ref; i = _i += 1) {
  console.debug(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=1;i<=0;i++){
    console.debug(i);
}
```

is equivalent to

```
var i = 1;
while(true) {
    console.debug(i);
    i++;
}
```

which in coffeescript is written as

```
i = 1
while true
  console.debug(i);
  i++;
```